# Is it more efficient to make a half-transparent PNG, or set opacity/alpha-filter on a non-transparent PNG?

Tags: html, css, png, opacity

The image in question will be reused about 5 times on each page of a website. I can either set the opacity to 0.5 and alpha(opacity) to 50 or I can lower the opacity of the image in Photoshop and save it with that setting.

Is there a better practice to follow?

Comment: This might be of interest for you? http://drupal.org/node/704182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check the 5th answer of linked question.](http://drupal.org/node/704182)

Comment: Drupal's issue tracker is not a Q&A site. They're two different things.

Comment: Ok, I agree with that. Actually I don't use Drupal so much. But the answer includes details about this question and should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If the image is going to have the same opacity wherever it's used, I don't see why you should need to add a bunch of `opacity` declarations with the same values everywhere you use it.

Lower the opacity in Photoshop, save it once, and use it everywhere. In case you need to change the image's opacity later, you can simply open the PSD, change it there, save it once more and the change will be reflected automatically without you having to change all the `opacity` styles again.

Comment: Well, I was looking for more of a comparison of performance efficiency, not of development. Sorry, should have specified.

Comment: @user745434: Well, focusing on what matters more — definitely *not* performance issues that don't even remotely concern web developers in the first place — is the better practice to follow. Personally, I'd rather not waste my time.

Comment: I wasn't aware that developers shouldn't concern themselves with performance issues ;). Wasting time sucks, but if the payoff is increasing user experience (especially for those poor IE users) and from that likely increasing conversion rate, I'd be willing to put in extra effort (to an extent). Regardless, thanks for the answer. It was a good point, I was just looking for the performance aspect.